# How can I make the vjs-big-play-button appear when the video is paused?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js

I am presently tinkering with [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/), an open source HTML5 video player. There is this big-play-button (*button name*) which is shown before the video is started. Upon clicking the button *"play"*, it disappears until the page is refreshed and the video has reloaded.

[image: Example]

I would like to modify the code so that the button re-appears when the video is paused.

Comment: I tried this: `vjs.BigPlayButton = vjs.Button.extend();

vjs.BigPlayButton.prototype.createEl = function(){
  return vjs.Button.prototype.createEl.call(this, 'div', {
    className: 'vjs-big-play-button',
    innerHTML: '<span aria-hidden="true"></span>',
    'aria-label': 'play video'
  });
};

vjs.BigPlayButton.prototype.onClick = function(){
  this.player_.play();
};`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can hide / show the big play button at any time using the VJS API, so no need to go about creating a new button. `bigPlayButton.show()` and `bigPlayButton.hide()` are what you're looking for. Here's an example that should get you on the right path:

```
var video = videojs('my-awesome-video');

video.on('pause', function() {
  this.bigPlayButton.show();

  // Now the issue is that we need to hide it again if we start playing
  // So every time we do this, we can create a one-time listener for play events.
  video.one('play', function() {
    this.bigPlayButton.hide();
  });
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsbin.com/bexogixokepo/1/edit).

**UPDATE FOR 5.0**

We (ok, it was me) broke it in 5.0 with a [css change](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/9e3a7b61595a2def395b75ce1f2c3d353d7b68cb/src/css/components/_big-play.scss#L46-L52). We need to revisit getting this approach to work (or whether it should), but in the meantime, adding these styles should do it.

```
.vjs-paused.vjs-has-started .vjs-big-play-button {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it was broken in Video.js 5.0 [styles](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/9e3a7b61595a2def395b75ce1f2c3d353d7b68cb/src/css/components/_big-play.scss#L46-L52). We should probably fix this method, but I'll add an updated answer.

Answer (score 30):

FWIW, in January 2017, someone [made a change](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/pull/3892/files) that displays the big-play-button on pause just by adding this class: `vjs-show-big-play-button-on-pause`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! This library has the worst documentation.

Comment: This should me the accepted answer. I have dug for this info and never located at videojs, so much apprecaited.

Comment: Big thanks! This still works in v8.0.4, march 2023.